# Find the derivative of $f(x)= \int_{\sin x}^{\tan x} \sqrt{t^{2}+t+1}\, \mathrm d t$

Tags: calculus

> Find the derivative of $$f(x)=\int_{\sin x}^{\tan x} \sqrt{t^{2}+t+1}\, 
>  \mathrm d t$$ with respect to $x$

So from may understanding, I need to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and then differentiate. I think the upper and lower limits are throwing me off.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The integral in the picture does not make sense. ${x}$ is not a free variable since it's being used in integration

Comment: Yes, this is horrendously heinous notation and your professor (or whoever gave you the exercise) should be punished. You need to write $\displaystyle\int_{\sin x}^{\tan x} g(t)\,dt$, and then it is indeed an application of the FTC. Hint: Write this as $\int_0^{\tan x} - \int_0^{\sin x}$. P.S. Please do not post questions that are images. Make the effort to type the question in the text with ChatJax.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think this sort of notation as well can be really bad for trying to understand this sort of concept, right? Like, the actual integration itself has nothing to do with the $x$ in the function definition, so I can imagine without knowing this is terrible notation it could really just confuse a student

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response. Rewriting the question really made things easier!!

Comment: you can apply fundamental theorem of calculus @IsraIsra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(t)$ denote the integrand $\sqrt{t^2+t+1}$. On the one hand, the FTC guarantees
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\sin x}^{\tan x} g(t)\, dt
$$
$$
=g(\tan(x))\cdot (\tan(x))' - g(\sin(x))\cdot (\sin(x))'
$$
$$
=g(\tan(x))\cdot \sec^2(x) - g(\sin(x))\cdot \cos(x)
$$
$$
=\sqrt{\tan^{2} (x)+\tan(x)+1}\cdot \sec^2(x) - \sqrt{\sin^{2} (x)+\sin(x)+1}\cdot \cos(x)
$$Were we masochisitic, we could compute the antiderivative using the substitution $(t+1/2)^2= (3/4)\tan^2(\theta)$ (note this cannot always be done, which is part of the power of the FTC), back-substitute, and then differentiate to verify we get the same result.
$$
\int \sqrt{t^2+t+1}\,dt = \int \sqrt{(t+1/2)^2+3/4}\,dt
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2} t\sqrt{t^2+t+1} +\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{t^2+t+1}+\frac{3}{8} \log \left(\frac{2
   t+1}{\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3} (2 t+1)^2+1}\right)
$$For instance, replacing $t$ with $\tan(x)$ at the upper limit and differentiating gives:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2} \tan (x) \sqrt{\tan ^2(x)+\tan (x)+1}+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\tan ^2(x)+\tan
   (x)+1}+\frac{3}{8} \log \left(\frac{2 \tan (x)+1}{\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3} (2 \tan
   (x)+1)^2+1}\right)\right)
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\tan ^2(x)+\tan (x)+1} \sec ^2(x)+\frac{\tan (x) \left(\sec ^2(x)+2 \tan (x)
   \sec ^2(x)\right)}{4 \sqrt{\tan ^2(x)+\tan (x)+1}}+\frac{\sec ^2(x)+2 \tan (x) \sec ^2(x)}{8
   \sqrt{\tan ^2(x)+\tan (x)+1}}+\frac{3 \left(\frac{2 \sec ^2(x)}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{2 (2 \tan
   (x)+1) \sec ^2(x)}{3 \sqrt{\frac{1}{3} (2 \tan (x)+1)^2+1}}\right)}{8 \left(\frac{2 \tan
   (x)+1}{\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3} (2 \tan (x)+1)^2+1}\right)}$$
$$
=\sqrt{\tan^2(x)+\tan(x)+1}\cdot \sec^2(x),
$$as promised. If you want, you can try the lower limit.

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU! You're the best. I have been stressing over this question for a while now and you have managed to make it seem so simple.

Answer (score 3):

That is very terrible notation. A clearer way of writing it is
\begin{align}
f(x):= \int_{\sin x}^{\tan x}\sqrt{t^2+t+1}\, dt
\end{align}
(or literally use any letter other than $x$ as the dummy integration variable, like $\xi,\mu,u,\nu,\eta$, or even use a funny symbol like $\sharp$, or, @, just not $x$).

Now, the Fundamental theorem of calculus says that:

> If $g$ is a continuous function and we define the function $G$ by the rule
> \begin{align}
> G(x):= \int_c^x g(t)\, dt
> \end{align}
> where $c$ is just some constant in the domain of $g$, then the function $G$ is also differentiable and $G'(x) = g(x)$.

Now, in order to apply the fundamental theorem to a function like
\begin{align}
f(x) = \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} g(t)\, dt,
\end{align}
the process is actually pretty simple. We just have to try to express $f$ in terms of simpler functions and apply the rules of differentiation we already know. So, for example, write:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)}g(t) \, dt \\
&= \int_c^{\beta(x)} g(t)\, dt - \int_c^{\alpha(x)} g(t)\, dt \\
&= G(\beta(x)) - G(\alpha(x)) \\
&= (G\circ \beta)(x) - (G\circ \alpha)(x)
\end{align}
Now, use the standard rules of differentiation (sum rule, chain rule and FTC) to figure out how to calculate $f'(x)$ in terms of $g,\alpha,\beta$ and their derivatives. Finally, for your particular example, just carefully pattern match everything and see what each function is; I leave this to you to do.

Comment: I think it's better not to just give formulas like this for students to memorize, although I realize that's a losing battle for me.

Comment: @TedShifrin I initially thought the confusion was only limited to the double usage of the letter $x$, but after your comment I see it could be more than that. So I've rewritten the answer to indicate how one should think about calculating such derivatives. And of course you're right that students shouldn't memorize such formulas; I don't even memorize them myself, because I always get them wrong, I just re-derive it on the spot whenever I need it:)